# authentication play framework redirection to pages doesn't work

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have login pages and I add some profiles, so after adding some and make the configuration of the controller for each profile and also the HTML pages. When I make the good username and the password. The redirection to the index page for each profile doesn't work and they redirect me to the page of the login

>

> public class Security extends Secure.Security {
>
> ```
> static boolean authenticate(String login, String password) {
>
>     return UserGcv.connect(login, password) != null;
>
> }
>
> static void onDisconnected() {
>     Application.index();
> }
>
> static void onAuthenticated() {
>     UserGcv user = UserGcv.find("byLogin", connected()).first();
>
>     Cache.set("user_" + session.get("username"), user, "30min");
>
>
>     switch (user.profil) {
>         case ADMIN:
>             Administration.showUsers();
>             break;
>         case DMC:
>             Catalogs.consultArticle();
>             break;
>         case DCGP:
>             DCGPArticle.consultArticleDCGP();
>             break;
>         case DCE:
>             DCEArticle.consultArticleDCE();
>             break;
>         case Planificateur:
>             Planificateur.composerVersion();
>             break;
>         case ValidAvantage:
>             ValidateurAvantage.homeValidateur();
>             break;
>         case PARAMETRAGE:
>             PARAMETRAGE.createParam();
>             break;
>         case ConfAvantage:
>             ConfigAvantage.homeConfigurateur();
>             break;
>
>     }
>
> } }
> ```

UserGCV.java

package models;

> @Entity @Table(name = "user_gcv") @With(Secure.class) public class
>   UserGcv extends Model {
>
> ```
> @Column(name = "user_name")
> public String userName;
> @Column(name = "user_last_name")
> public String userLastName;
> @Column(name = "user_direction")
> public String userDirection;
> @Column(name = "user_phone_number")
> public Integer userPhoneNumber;
> @Column(name = "user_cin")
> public Integer userCin;
> @Column(name = "user_fonction")
> public String userFonction;
> @Column(name = "login")
> public String login;
> @Column(name = "password")
> public String password;
> @Column(name = "user_mail_address")
> @Email
> public String userMailAddress;
> @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
> public Profil profil;
> @Column(name = "actif")
> public int actif;
> @OneToMany(mappedBy = "utilisateur")
> List<Trace> traces = new ArrayList();
>
> public UserGcv(Long id, String userName, String userLastName,
>         String userDirection, Integer userPhoneNumber, Integer userCin,
>         String userFonction, String login, String password,
>         String userMailAddress, Profil profil, int actif) {
>     this.id = id;
>     this.userName = userName;
>     this.userLastName = userLastName;
>     this.userDirection = userDirection;
>     this.userPhoneNumber = userPhoneNumber;
>     this.userCin = userCin;
>     this.userFonction = userFonction;
>     this.login = login;
>     this.password = password;
>     this.userMailAddress = userMailAddress;
>     this.profil = profil;
>     this.actif = actif;
>
> }
>
> public UserGcv() {
> }
>
> public static UserGcv connect(String login, String password) {
>
>     return find("select distinct u from UserGcv u where login=? and password=? and actif=?", login, password, 1).first();
>
> }
>
> public UserGcv(String login, String password) {
>     this.login = login;
>     this.password = password;
>
> }
> ```

```
public UserGcv(String userName, String userLastName, String userDirection, Integer userPhoneNumber, Integer userCin, String userFonction, String login, String password, String userMailAddress, Profil profil, int actif) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userLastName = userLastName;
    this.userDirection = userDirection;
    this.userPhoneNumber = userPhoneNumber;
    this.userCin = userCin;
    this.userFonction = userFonction;
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
    this.userMailAddress = userMailAddress;
    this.profil = profil;
    this.actif = actif;
}
```

> ```
> @Override
> public String toString() {
>     return "" + id;
> }
>
> public static List<UserGcv> findAllUsers() {
>     return UserGcv.find("order by userName asc").fetch();
> }
>
> public boolean isAdmin() {
>     return Profil.ADMIN.equals(profil);
> }
>
> public boolean isDMC() {
>     return Profil.DMC.equals(profil);
> }
>
> public boolean isDCGP() {
>     return Profil.DCGP.equals(profil);
> }
>
> public boolean isPlanificateur() {
>     return Profil.Planificateur.equals(profil);
> }
>
> public boolean isDCE() {
>     return Profil.DCE.equals(profil);
> }
>
> public boolean isParametrage() {
>     return Profil.PARAMETRAGE.equals(profil);
> }
>
> public boolean isConfigAvantage() {
>     return Profil.ConfAvantage.equals(profil);
> }
>
> public boolean isValidateurAvantage() {
>     return Profil.ValidAvantage.equals(profil);
> } }
> ```

Routes

```
    # Routes

    # Import Secure routes
    #*       /                                       module:secure 
GET  /                                           Secure.login 
POST     /                                       Secure.authenticate 
GET      /logout                                 Secure.logout

    # Home page
    #GET     /                                       Application.index

    # Administration page 
GET     /administration/user/edit/{id}         Administration.editUser 
GET     /administration/new                    Administration.newUser
 GET     /administration/user/save/{id}         Administration.save 
POST    /administration/new                    Administration.save 
GET     /administration/script                 Administration.telechargerScript GET     /administration/download      Administration.download 
GET     /administration/details            Administration.detailsVersion 
GET     /administration/traces             Administration.consulterTraces
 GET     /administration/historique       Administration.exportCSVFile

    # DMC page 
GET     /catalog/index                          Catalogs.index
 GET     /catalog/search                         Catalogs.searchArticle 
GET     /catalog/consult                        Catalogs.modifArticle 
GET     /catalog/search                         Catalogs.searchArticleDes
 GET     /pack/modify                            Catalogs.modifPack 
GET /pack/consult                           Catalogs.consultPack

    GET     /catalogues/getListArticle/?           Catalogs.getListArticle 
POST    /pack/new                              Catalogs.savePack

    # DCGP page 
GET     /dcepack/consultpackdce                 DCEPack.consultPackDCE 
GET     /dcgp/articles                          DCGP.allArticle 
GET     /dcgp/delete                            DCGP.deleteArticle 
GET     /dcgp/facture                           DCGP.generateFacture 
GET     /dcgp/modify                            DCGP.modifyArticle 
GET     /dcgp/valid                             DCGP.validPack 
GET     /dcgppack/consultpackdcgp               DCGPPack.consultPackDCGP

    # Planificateur page

GET     /Planificateur/composer          Planificateur.composerVersion 
GET     /Planificateur/planifierAvantage Planificateur.homePlanificateur

    # Parametrage page 
POST    /parametrage/new                              Parametrage.saveParam
    # Configurateur Avantage pages 
GET     /ConfigAvantage/homeConfigurateur     ConfigAvantage.homeConfigurateur GET     /ConfigAvantage/modifierAvantage/?   ConfigAvantage.modifierAvantage 
GET     /ConfigAvantage/searchPackToAffectation/?ConfigAvantage.searchPackToAffectation 
GET     /VersionAvantage/goToGPS                    VersionAvantage.goToGPS 
GET     /ConfigAvantage/viewAvantageDetails/?     ConfigAvantage.viewAvantageDetails 
GET     /ConfigAvantage/affectationPackView/?     ConfigAvantage.affectationPackView

    #Validateur Avantage Pages 
 GET    /ValidateurAvantage/homeValidateur         ValidateurAvantage.homeValidateur

    # Ignore favicon requests 
GET     /favicon.ico                            404

    # Map static resources from the /app/public folder to the /public path 
GET     /public/                                staticDir:public


    # Import CRUD routes
    *      /admin                                   module:crud

    # Catch all
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

i ckecked the method onAuthenticated in Secure.Security , it return null for the url

```
static void onAuthenticated() {

        UserGcv user = UserGcv.find("byLogin", connected()).first();
        Cache.set("user_" + session.get("username"), user, "60min");
        System.err.println("usecccccccccccccccccccccr"+user);
        switch (user.profil) {
            case ADMIN:
                Administration.showUsers();
                break;
            case DMC:
                Catalogs.consultArticle();
                break;
            case DCGP:
                DCGPArticle.consultArticleDCGP();
                break;
            case DCE:
                DCEArticle.consultArticleDCE();
                break;
            case Planificateur:
                Planificateur.composerVersion();
                break;
            case ValidAvantage:
                ValidateurAvantage.homeValidateur();
                break;
            case PARAMETRAGE:
                PARAMETRAGE.createParam();
                break;
            case ConfAvantage:
               ConfigAvantage.homeConfigurateur();
                break;
        }
```

Comment: i checked the method onAuthenticated in Secure.Security return null for URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the custom security class when the class extend from Secure.Security he didn't overide the method onAuthenticated So the solution was to impliment the custom onAuthenticated into the default class

```
 public static class Security extends Controller {

        /**
         * @Deprecated
         *
         * @param username
         * @param password
         * @return
         */
        static boolean authentify(String username, String password) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        /**
         * This method is called during the authentication process. This is
         * where you check if the user is allowed to log in into the system.
         * This is the actual authentication process against a third party
         * system (most of the time a DB).
         *
         * @param username
         * @param password
         * @return true if the authentication process succeeded
         */
        static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * This method checks that a profile is allowed to view this
         * page/method. This method is called prior to the method's controller
         * annotated with the @Check method.
         *
         * @param profile
         * @return true if you are allowed to execute this controller method.
         */
        static boolean check(String profile) {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * This method returns the current connected username
         *
         * @return
         */
        static String connected() {
            return session.get("username");
        }

        /**
         * Indicate if a user is currently connected
         *
         * @return true if the user is connected
         */
        static boolean isConnected() {
            return session.contains("username");
        }

        /**
         * This method is called after a successful authentication. You need to
         * override this method if you with to perform specific actions (eg.
         * Record the time the user signed in)
         */
        static void onAuthenticated() {

            UserGcv user = UserGcv.find("byLogin", connected()).first();

            Cache.set("user_" + session.get("username"), user, "60min");

            switch (user.profil) {
                case ADMIN:
                    Administration.showUsers();
                    break;
                case DMC:
                    Catalogs.consultArticle();
                    break;
                case DCGP:
                    DCGPArticle.consultArticleDCGP();
                    break;
                case DCE:
                    DCEArticle.consultArticleDCE();
                    break;
                case Planificateur:
                    Planificateur.composerVersion();
                    break;
                case PARAMETRAGE:
                    PARAMETRAGE.createParam();
                    break;
                case ConfAvantage:
                    ConfigAvantage.homeConfigurateur();
                    break;
                case ValidAvantage:
                    ValidateurAvantage.homeValidateur();
                    break;
                case PlanifDSC:
                    PlanifDSC.homePlanifDSC();
                    break;
            }
        }
```